# Render aria-current attribute with blazor's NavLink component

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, wai-aria

Blazor's `NavLink` component detects whether the link refers to the current page, and sets the `active` class.

It is customary to also set the `aria-current="page"` attribute, when it is part of a menu.

Can the component do that somehow? Or could I wrap it in a custom component that does this?

I can't find an extension point that easily allows for this: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.routing.navlink?view=aspnetcore-6.0), [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ce78832442d91ca307ca8366bafdc9003ea46bc9/src/Components/Web/src/Routing/NavLink.cs).

Comment: Umm add the extra line to the builder. Or use CSS to add it for you based on the presence of 'active'?

Comment: @BrianParker *"Add the extra line"*: if I do it from outside (from the page containing the component) how do I detect that link is active? *"Or use css"*: how do I use css to add an html attribute? Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Reading further add the attribute with CSS will not be visible to the reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending the existing `NavLink`

```
public class NavLinkExtended : NavLink
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "a");
        builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);
        builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", CssClass);

        if(CssClass.Contains("active"))
        {
            builder.AddAttribute(3, "aria-current", "page");
            builder.AddContent(4, ChildContent);
            builder.CloseElement();
        }
        else
        {
            builder.AddContent(3, ChildContent);
            builder.CloseElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hah I beat you by a few minutes... :-) but I'm still gonna mark yours as the answer as your cs is cleaner than my razor. Note though how I've done it: 1) `CssClass` is nullable, and 2) I've not assumed "active", I instead did `ActiveClass ?? "active"`.

Comment: Also thanks for pushing me over 10k rep. Only a few hundred for you too... Nice way to start the week.

Comment: Your welcome thought you would like that ;-)

Comment: Should else block not have "5" instead of "3"? I've never fully grokked that render tree stuff.

Comment: They should be sequential I edited the answer to -> 0 1 2 3 4

Comment: I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/44913) for the NavLink class.

Comment: I was going to suggest that great Idea.

Comment: The PR was merged, so it will be available in v8 (next November).

Comment: The PR has been refactored.  You only need the if round the `AddAttribute` call and then set the AddContent as sequence 4 outside the if (no need for if else)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.

`AriaNavLink.razor`:

```cs
<NavLink class=@CssClass @attributes=Attributes>
  @ChildContent
</NavLink>


@inherits NavLink
@code {

  private const string _defaultActiveClass = "active";
  private Dictionary<string, object>? _attributes;

  private IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> Attributes
  {
    get
    {
      if (_attributes != null) return _attributes;
      _attributes = AdditionalAttributes != null
        ? new Dictionary<string, object>(AdditionalAttributes)
        : new Dictionary<string, object>();
      // the trick to inferring "active" indirectly:
      var isActive = CssClass?.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries).Contains(ActiveClass ?? _defaultActiveClass) ?? false;
      if (isActive)
        _attributes.Add("aria-current", "page");
      return _attributes;
    }
  }

}
```

Some page using bootstrap:

```xml
<li class="nav-item">
  <AriaNavLink href="/foo" class="nav-link" foo="bar">
    <i class="some-icon"></i>
    Foo
  </AriaNavLink>
</li>
```

Comment: See @BrianParker's solution for a cleaner cs-only approach. But use my trick above to make the code more robust.

Comment: if i use your AriaNavLink with `href="/" Match="NavLinkMatch.All"`, then this AriaNavLink keeps the `active` class when visiting a sub URL like `"/stuff"`. this behavior is different from the standard NavLink

Comment: nevermind. i solved it by adding the `Match` attribute: with `<NavLink class=@CssClass @attributes=Attributes Match="@Match">` instead of `<NavLink class=@CssClass @attributes=Attributes>`

Comment: why did you use the variable `_attributes`? i'm guessing it is supposed to act like cache. when would one benefit from this? it seems untypical to cache properties in Blazor. i like your solution because it seems to touch the least amount

Comment: @symbiont Sorry it's been a while so I don't remember. But v8 has this functionality built-in... check [my PR](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/44913) here.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me for not being exact, but...  I would approach this with something like...

```
aria-current="@(route == nav route) ? "page" : "" ")
```

and then figure out how to detect the route of the current page and the configured nav route for the thing you're modifying.

Then, if you have a LOT of these nav things and you don't want to duplicate the logic all over the place.... write a method that does the above and add that to your code like...

[image]

Comment: Exactly... But how is that done? Also, that is a lot of busy work on a large menu, do you know if it can be done inside the component to keep it clean?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Your new code supposes a custom component that wraps `NavLink`. And `IsActive` is the key here, but that info is not exposed by the component.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't...  you're putting your NavLink on a page... right?  Every page can have code blocks.  it's the code block of the page, or the component which renders your menu, where you're putting your code.  it might not be the cleanest, but it's relatively straight forward.  There may be a cleaner way to do it using some properties of the NavLink itself...  I'll look at that and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. I understand what you mean, but that code misses the crucial detail for `IsActive`. See my answer below for a working solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I put you on the right track.  I did mention I wasn't being exact...

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is a good solution for now. When v8 is released (probably November 2023), the functionality will be built-in. The merged PR [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/44913).